# x3dom, rotation and hiding shapes

Tags: javascript, x3dom

I'm currently working on this using x3dom: http://folk.ntnu.no/emilh/modell.htm , and I have two problems.

First one is that when I load my model, it appears in a awkward position, I'd like to automaticly flip it and zoom so that you see it from a better side. Currently I have no idea how to do this.

Secondly I'm trying to make a button that toggles the visibility on the outer shell of the model, I've identified the shapes that builds up the shell, but I don't know how to toggle their visibility. So if I have the ...., what can I do to it to make it hidden?

Sorry for mixing Norwegian and English on the site :P

And thanks in advance!

Comment: Figured out both problems, still having troubles setting the zoom level on load though, but I think I'll figure it out soon enough

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways of dealing with the zoom level.

1. Change the scale attribute of your transform, making the shape bigger.
2. Add a viewpoint node, like so
   `<viewpoint id="view_id" position='0 10 15' orientation='-1 0 0 0.5'></viewpoint>`

The position and orientation values will depend on your scene.

Answer (score 2):

It is asked long time ago but for people who have same problem the solution is like following:

You can use

```html
<vievpoint position="0 0 250">
```

to change default zoom of your object. first and second parameters for x y coordinates and third one for zoom. If you want to zoom out you can use positive values, to zoom in you can use negative values.

Whole code is like this:

```html
  <x3d width='500px' height='400px'>
   <scene>
     <viewpoint position="0 0 250"></viewpoint>
     <tramsform>
       <inline url="path">
     </transform>
    </scene>
  </x3d>
```

Answer (score 0):

For the visibility you can use the transparency attribute on the material tag. http://doc.x3dom.org/author/Shape/Material.html

The shape is still there but you can modify the transparency of it.